# Key Listener for Raspberry Pi Zero via SSH

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I am trying to write a key listener for a headless Raspberry Pi Zero that I am connected to via SSH; the RPi is set up to imitate an HID keyboard, and I want to pause / resume a macro from the RPi to my PC by pressing certain keys, hence the key listener.

I understand that pynput does not work with a headless set-up due to requiring a display. I found another Python module called [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) that should work, and I followed the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57098826/16217757), but my program is still unable to detect keypresses.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.